# What's the meaning of "どアップしんどい"?

Tags: translation, words, slang, internet-slang

I found this sentence in a manga and I can't understand what it means.
どアップ (or ドアップ) should mean close up, while しんどい means tiring, bothersome, hard etc., but what do they mean when they are put together?

The scene goes like this: Two girls are nose-to-nose , one of them is completely enthralled by the beauty of the other, and in her inner dialogue she says "“どアップしんどい" before praising the eyes and the eyelashes of the other girl.

I've seen it used as a hashtag on Instagram (on close up pictures) but that didn't help me at all. Can someone help me out?

Comment: It's open to so many interpretations. Could you provide the context?

Comment: Sure. Two girls are nose-to-nose , one of them is completely enthralled by the beauty of the other, and in her inner dialogue she says "“どアップしんどい" before praising the eyes and the eyelashes of the other girl.

Comment: Thank you, I never imagined of such a situation. Could you add it to your question?

Comment: Done, I hope this will make things more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- どアップ
  Yes, it means close-up. Beyond that, it usually describes an extreme close-up shot that whole picture is covered up by the object ([often is a person's face](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%A9%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97&tbm=isch)). In this specific case, it mentions the closeness with the other that she sees her どアップ face. The prefix ど makes a very strong slang that means "total(ly)", "absolute(ly)", or "f***ing".
- しんどい
  The word literally means "fatigued" or "fatiguing", but also is [a recent slang](https://togetter.com/li/1033826) that mostly used by otaku fangirls to express they are in the climax of excitement that they "can't bear anymore". If your description of "enthralled" is correct, it might be used in this sense.

The sentence seemingly tells that she is しんどい being どアップ, though no particles between them. So, some free translations would be:

> The close-up stare drains me out!
>   The close-up stare is killing me!

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the help and for the useful informations! I guess "her stare is killing me" would be a good adaptation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I take your advice! Note that I didn't actually mean "her" stare, but the situation they stare the other's face in zero distance. Obviously I'm not a native English speaker.